# Relaunching a dialog programmatically

Tags: android, dialog, datepicker

My app uses a date picker dialog.
The dialog is implemented in a class that implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener.
My class therefore has a method OnDateSet();
In this method, I would like to check, whether the date selected is 'acceptable' (In my program, some dates just do not make sense)
How can I relaunch the dialog from within OnDateSet();

Answer (score 0):

you're misunderstanding how `DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener` works, i think.  this callback is triggered whenever the user has clicked the 'OK' button, indicating that they are done setting the date in the dialog.  this callback is called every time the dialog confirmation button is clicked, so this is where you want to call your check method.  you can then display a `Dialog` or `Toast` message to the user, notifying them that the Date is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, OnDateListener will be triggered each time the user sets a date. And I do want to Launch Toast AND a dialog, The toast telling the user that the date entered is incorrect and a Dialog being the same DatePicker dialog.
I have managed to do so by calling back into the activity that lauched the dialog where I implemented a 'relauchDatePicker()' method that starts a date picker and creates a toast.
I was hoping that there was a way to do this directly in my dialog class java, rather than my activity.